# SQL Query pulling same field with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, employee records (id, firstName, lastName) and violation (violatorId, supervisorId).

My query pulls a list of violators and supervisors. I would like to rather than displaying the id of the person, display their first and last name. So this is my query so far...

```
SELECT 
emp.firstName as vFirstName,
emp.lastName as vLastname,
v.violatorId, 
v.supervisorId,
emp.firstName as sFirstName,
emp.lastName as sLastName
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN violator v
ON violatorId = emp.id
```

So this will return the first and last name information for the violator, but not for the supervisor. Sample Output:

```
Violator vFirstName  vLastName   Supervisor sFirstName sLastName
1        Jon         Smith       20         Jon        Smith
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Is your supervisorId referencing the Employee table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  e1.firstName AS violatorFirstName,
  e1.lastName AS violatorLastName,
  e2.firstName AS supervisorFirstName,
  e2.lastName AS supervisorLastName
FROM violator v
LEFT JOIN employee e1 ON v.violatorId = e1.id
LEFT JOIN employee e2 ON v. supervisorId = e2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to join once more to `employee`:

```
SELECT emp.firstName AS vFirstName, emp.lastName AS vLastName,
       v.violatorId AS vId, v.supervisorId AS sId,
       s.firstName AS sFirstName, s.lastName AS sLastName
FROM employee emp
LEFT JOIN violator v ON v.violatorId = emp.id
LEFT JOIN employee s ON v.supervisorId = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach-1**

```
SELECT 
  e1.violatorId AS violatorId ,
  e1.firstName AS violatorName,
  e2.supervisorId AS supervisorId ,
  e2.firstName AS supervisorName
FROM violator v
LEFT JOIN employee e1 ON v.violatorId = e1.id
LEFT JOIN employee e2 ON v. supervisorId = e2.id
```

**Approach-2**

```
SELECT 
    v.violatorId,
    emp.firstName AS violatorName, 
    v.supervisorId,
    (SELECT firstName FROM employee WHERE employee.id = v.supervisorId) AS supervisorName
FROM 
    employee emp
LEFT JOIN 
    violator v
ON 
    violatorId = emp.id
```